# Can Blender 2.79 add a completely empty new UV Map?

Tags: uv

I want to add another UV map.
I click the "+" button.
But every time, it copies also the previous uv map. When I unwrap a new one, the old one also there.
So, can Blender 2.79 add an empty UV Map?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" UV? The faces of the object are always mapped in a UV, even if it's not properly unwrapped.

Comment: Oh, so I just have to put the part of unwrap map I don't need aside?